# Comparaison row by row with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this:

```
ordre/id /date /origine /destination /horaire A /horaire B

1 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
2 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00
3 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
4 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:20/14:00 
5 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
6 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
7 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00
8 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00
9 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Lyon/10:00/12:00
```

I want to add a new column `note` that will store comparaison value for each object groupby same `id` and `date`, any change `'date /origine /destination /horaire A /horaire B'` so note **True**

example:

- for row 9, `destination` is lyon where is difference previous line 'marseille' so `note` is **True**
- for row 4, we have a diffrences data `'Horaire A'` and `'Horaire B'` so `note` is **True**

Output:

```
1 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
2 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
3 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00
4 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Lyon/10:00/12:00/True
5 1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00/True
6 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00
7 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00
8 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/True
9 1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:20/14:00/True
```

I wrote this code:

```
df['Note'] = df.groupby(['Date','id']).apply(lambda x: (x['Origine'] != x['Origine'].shift(-1)) | (x['Destination'] != x['Destination'].shift(-1)) | (x['Horaire A'] != x['Horaire A'].shift(-1)) | (x['Horaire B'] != x['Horaire B'].shift(-1)))
df['Note'] = df['Note'].shift(1)
```

But this program gives an error: ***incompatible index of inserted column with frame index***

How do i fix it?

Comment: Why are the destinations different in the output dataframe? Also, in the example for row 9 you say that the previous line is 'marseille', but it is 'Bordeaux'. Could you make your example consistent? It would really help to understand your problem.

Comment: Try using `group_keys` argument as such: `df['Note'] = df.groupby(['Date','id'], group_keys = False).apply ...`

Comment: can you provide your dataframe as dictionary or constructor? there are weird `'/'` as separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can compare the rows with the shifted rows, per group. If `any` field mismatches, then we set the output as `True`.

I am relying on "ordre" as unique key here to `merge` back to the original data, but you could use the index if this is not the case. In such case, "order" should be dropped of the groupby.

```
df.merge(df.set_index('ordre')
           .groupby(['id', 'date'], group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda d: d.ne(d.shift().bfill()).any(1))
           .rename('diff_previous'),
         left_on='ordre', right_index=True
        )
```

output:

```
   ordre    id        date origine destination horaire A horaire B  diff_previous
0      1  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00          False
1      2  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     09:00     13:00          False
2      3  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00          False
3      4  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     10:20     14:00           True
4      5  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00          False
5      6  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00          False
6      7  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     09:00     13:00           True
7      8  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     10:00     14:00           True
8      9  1112  2021-03-11   Paris        Lyon     10:00     12:00           True
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code to generate the DataFrame:

```py
data = {
    "ordre": range(1, 10),
    "id": [1112, 1114, 1112, 1114, 1112, 1112, 1114, 1114, 1112],
    "date": [
        "2021-03-11",
        "2021-05-11",
        "2021-03-11",
        "2021-05-11",
        "2021-03-11",
        "2021-03-11",
        "2021-05-11",
        "2021-05-11",
        "2021-03-11",
    ],
    "origine": ["Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris"],
    "destination": [
        "Marseille",
        "Bordeaux",
        "Marseille",
        "Bordeaux",
        "Marseille",
        "Marseille",
        "Bordeaux",
        "Bordeaux",
        "Lyon",
    ],
    "horaire A": ["10:00", "09:00", "10:00", "10:20", "10:00", "10:00", "09:00", "10:00", "10:00"],
    "horaire B": ["14:00", "13:00", "14:00", "14:00", "14:00", "14:00", "13:00", "14:00", "12:00"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then the idea is to:

1. Sort the data by `("date", "id", "ordre")`
2. Set `"note"` to `True` if :

   a. `("date", "id")` are the same as previous row

   b. One of `("origine", "destination", "horaire A", "horaire B")` is different from the previous row

Which translates into:

```py
index_cols = ["date", "id"]
compare_cols = ["origine", "destination", "horaire A", "horaire B"]

df = df.sort_values(by=index_cols+["ordre"])
shifted_compare = df[index_cols + compare_cols].shift(1).eq(df[index_cols + compare_cols])

df["note"] = shifted_compare[index_cols].all(axis=1) & ~shifted_compare[compare_cols].all(axis=1)
```

Which outputs to:

```py
>>> df.sort_values(by="ordre")
   ordre    id        date origine destination horaire A horaire B   note
0      1  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00  False
1      2  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     09:00     13:00  False
2      3  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00  False
3      4  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     10:20     14:00   True
4      5  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00  False
5      6  1112  2021-03-11   Paris   Marseille     10:00     14:00  False
6      7  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     09:00     13:00   True
7      8  1114  2021-05-11   Paris    Bordeaux     10:00     14:00   True
8      9  1112  2021-03-11   Paris        Lyon     10:00     12:00   True
```